Python Singleton - Avoid "None" reference
I have created a class that I"m attempting to implement a Singleton pattern on. When __new__ for the class is fired off, I check to see if a class-wide list of instances has a length > 0 or not, and only return the class instance if it's 0 (i.e there isn't already an instance). I've gotten this to MOSTLY work, and can validate that it isn't intstaniating additional objects - however, the reference still exists, even though it returns None. I'm not sure if there is a way to avoid this, as ideally I don't want an empty reference if the instance isn't returned.
The code:
class Dog(Mammal):
    _instances = []
    _type: str

    def __new__(cls,type):
        if len(cls._instances) == 0:
            instance = super().__new__(cls)
            print("no classes yet")
            return instance
        else:
            return

    def __init__(self,type):
        self._type = type
        print("creating a new {} dog".format(self._type))
        Dog._instances.append(self)


    def sleep(self):
        return "Zzzzz...."

    @classmethod
    def totalDogs(cls):
        return len(cls._instances)

# Returns a viable Dog object 
fido = Dog("Yorkie")
print(fido.sleep())
rey = Dog("Matlese")
# Returns None, but doesn't throw an error since the reference (rey) still exists:
print(rey)

# Validates that there is only 1 instance
print(fido.totalDogs())

While it's clear an instance hasn't been created and assigned to 'rey', the reference is still valid, although returns None. Is there any way to avoid this? Do I need to raise an Error of some type? Or simply rely on garbage collection?

Singleton usually means that you return an already instantiated object without constructing a new one. Not just return nothing. The alternative would be to prevent instantiation by raising an error, yes. But you can’t have the instantiation succeed without error and not return anything and also not have None. There’s just nothing left it could be.

In Python, return with no argument is equivalent to return None. So what are you expecting it to assign to rey?

If you try to use any Dog methods on rey you'll get an error, since it doesn't actually contain a Dog instance.
